# Android image download from server?

Tags: android

```
my logcat---------::


09-07 19:55:51.623: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:55:51.634: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:55:52.033: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1680): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1896 objects / 518112 bytes in 97ms
09-07 19:55:52.364: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:55:53.254: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1680): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 822 objects / 539696 bytes in 67ms
09-07 19:56:01.514: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110805085124_wtpa.logo.png
09-07 19:56:01.584: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110805084621_wtpa.logo.png
09-07 19:56:01.643: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110805025050_chuckie liv.ashx.jpg
09-07 19:56:01.684: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110805024007_space vegas.ashx.jpg
09-07 19:56:01.914: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:01.953: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:02.714: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:02.754: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110805023407_blush vegas.ashx.jpg
09-07 19:56:02.834: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110805022856_Savoy vegas.ashx.jpg
09-07 19:56:02.944: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1680): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1058 objects / 490016 bytes in 80ms
09-07 19:56:02.944: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:02.944: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:03.894: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:03.923: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110808101519_DSC0028-Ti.jpg
09-07 19:56:04.104: INFO/System.out(1680): ImageUrl :: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110729152914_wtpa.logo.png
09-07 19:56:04.604: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:04.634: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:05.004: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1680): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 966 objects / 515008 bytes in 80ms
09-07 19:56:05.404: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:05.434: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:05.464: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
09-07 19:56:06.194: DEBUG/skia(1680): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

my code is ::

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.EventLogTags.Description;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    private ProgressBar indicator;

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {

        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    }

    public void DisplayImage(String url, Context activity, ImageView imageView,
            ProgressBar pbar) {

        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            this.indicator = pbar;
            indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            this.indicator = pbar;
            indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Context activity, ImageView imageView) {
        // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
        // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        // start thread if it's not started yet
        if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {

            HttpGet httpRequest = null;

            try {


                int pos = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
                URI uri = new URI(url.substring(0, pos)
                        + URLEncoder.encode(url.substring(pos), "UTF-8"));
               //URL imgUrl = new URL(decodeUrl);
                httpRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                System.out.println("Error ::" + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);

            /*
             * Bitmap bitmap = null; URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
             * HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
             * .openConnection(); conn.connect(); conn.getDoOutput();
             * 
             * 
             * conn.setConnectTimeout(30000); conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
             * 
             * InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
             * 
             * OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f); Utils.CopyStream(is,
             * os); os.close(); bitmap = decodeFile(f); return bitmap;
             */
            return bm;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap gonextUrl(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {

            URL imgUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(imgUrl.toURI());

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);

            return bm;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bm;
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread() {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    // stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        // removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image) {
            for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();) {
                if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {

                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0) {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad) {
                            photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if (tag != null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)) {

                            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp,
                                    photoToLoad.imageView, indicator);
                            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView
                                    .getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if (Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;

        // private ProgressBar indicator1;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i, ProgressBar indicator) {
            this.bitmap = b;
            this.imageView = i;
            // this.indicator1 = indicator;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                // indicator1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else
                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a question in all that?

Comment: no  in some url problem i have 15 image url out of 114 url ...There are prblm either url or bitmap idont know ????

Comment: or any way to download big image which size is 1000 * 1200 and size is more than 5 to 8 MB?? U have any application in android ...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this function loadImageFromUrl(" http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110805085124_wtpa.logo.png")  to get image bitmap from imageurl

```
public static Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
                InputStream inputStream;Bitmap b;
                try {
                        inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                        BitmapFactory.Options bpo=  new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        bpo.inSampleSize=2;
                       b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(inputStream), null,bpo );
                        return  b;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
//                  return null;
        }
```

this is the class for PatchInputStream

```
public class PatchInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
          public PatchInputStream(InputStream in) {
            super(in);
          }
          public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            long m = 0L;
            while (m < n) {
              long _m = in.skip(n-m);
              if (_m == 0L) break;
              m += _m;
            }
            return m;
          }
        }
```

You can also modify your code to prevent error.Just you need to add  PatchInputStream(inputStream) in BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(inputStream), null,bpo );

Comment: Got Exception and App force close_______________>>>>>>                     09-07 20:16:00.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1729): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
09-07 20:16:00.433: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1729): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110729132422_wet rep every sun.jpg

Comment: what is the url you are passing in the method  loadImageFromUrl(String url)

Comment: http://www.heresmyparty.com/cms/components/com_chronocontact/uploads/add_event_form/20110722122552_mood%20fri.jpg

Comment: there is no such file for your url and that is why this   error java.io.FileNotFoundException: is coming

Comment: You can check it in the browser whether file is there or not .otherwise you are not passing the correct url.